# Multithreading Program; Threads that make more threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm currently working on a program that takes an array of 10000 random numbers, splits it evenly with five threads, and those five threads split further into 20 threads each evenly. The purpose is to find the ultimate minimum number from that original 10000 random number array.

I believe I'm on the right track. Upon further examination, something is wrong with my array traversal on level 1. I can only see one of the first 5 thread's 20 threads return. The information that comes back appears correct, but when I try to cout the information as it is happening, I get blank space for the return minimums of 4 of the L1 thread's L2 threads. (Sorry if that's a bit confusing.)

Would anyone be able to give me any tips on what to look out for? I will provide the code below.

Bear in mind, efficiency is not the goal of this program. Demonstrating multithreading is.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>

/*
Macros were used to make modulation easier and to ease reading of the code
*/

#define L1_THREADS 5  //# of level 1 threads
#define L2_THREADS 20 //# of level 2 threads
//#define L1_ARRAY 5  //eventually unused
#define L2_ARRAY 2000 //size of level 2 array

using namespace std;

//structure to house the Thread Parameters required
struct ThreadParameters{
  int* array;
  int start;
  int end;
  int smallest;
};

//function to find the minimum value at the bottom level of the thread spread
void* find_min(void* args){
  struct ThreadParameters* specs = (struct ThreadParameters*)args;
  int *array = specs->array;
  int start = specs->start;
  int end = specs->end;
  int smallest = array[start];

  for(int i = start; i < end; i++){
    if(array[i] < smallest){
      smallest = array[i];
    }
  }

  specs->smallest = smallest;

  return NULL;
}

//function to find the minimum value of the values returned by the threads it creates
void* find_first(void* args){
  pthread_t threads2[L2_THREADS] = {0};
  struct ThreadParameters thread2_parameters[L2_THREADS] = {0};

  struct ThreadParameters* specs = (struct ThreadParameters*)args;
  int *array = specs->array;
  int start = specs->start;
  int end = specs ->end;
  int smallest = array[start];

  //Level 1, creates the 20 threads for level 2
  for(int i = 0; i < L2_THREADS; i++){
    thread2_parameters[i].array = array;
    thread2_parameters[i].start = i*(L2_ARRAY/L2_THREADS);
    thread2_parameters[i].end = (i+1)*(L2_ARRAY/L2_THREADS);
    pthread_create(&threads2[i], NULL, find_min, &thread2_parameters[i]);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < L2_THREADS; i++){
    pthread_join(threads2[i], NULL);
  }

  cout << "Minimums from L2 threads: ";

  for(int i = start; i < L2_THREADS; i++){
    cout << "[" << thread2_parameters[i].smallest << "]";
    if(thread2_parameters[i].smallest < smallest){
      smallest = thread2_parameters[i].smallest;
    }
  }

  cout << endl;

  specs->smallest = smallest;

  return NULL;
}

int main(){

  time_t t;
  int n = 10000;
  int randnum[n];    /* array of random numbers */

  /* Initialize random number generator */
  srand((unsigned) time(&t));

  /* Generate random numbers */
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    randnum[i] = rand()%10000 +1;
  }

  /*  end of random number generation code */

  pthread_t threads1[L1_THREADS] = {0};
  struct ThreadParameters thread1_parameters[L1_THREADS] = {0};
  //int min[L1_ARRAY];

  int smallest;
  smallest = randnum[0];

  //Level 0, creates the first five threads for level 1
  for(int i = 0; i < L1_THREADS; i++){
    thread1_parameters[i].array = randnum;
    thread1_parameters[i].start = i*(n/L1_THREADS);
    thread1_parameters[i].end = (i+1)*(n/L1_THREADS);
    pthread_create(&threads1[i], NULL, find_first, &thread1_parameters[i]);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < L1_THREADS; i++){
    pthread_join(threads1[i], NULL);
  }

  cout << "Minimums from L1 threads: ";

  //finds the ultimate minimum after L1 threads return with their values
  for(int i = 0; i < L1_THREADS; i++){
    cout << "[" << thread1_parameters[i].smallest << "]";
    if(thread1_parameters[i].smallest < smallest){
      smallest = thread1_parameters[i].smallest;
    }
  }

  cout << "\nThe ultimate minimum is " << smallest << endl;

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: How many cores do you have? Normally having 2x the threads as cores is a good limit and anything beyond that has diminishing returns, often severely.

Comment: which c++ version are you using? Since c++11 there is `std::thread` which is much more conenient to work with, eg you dont have to mess around with `void*`

Comment: Just off the top of my head, 100 threads for 10,000 numbers sounds like too many. The overhead and  bookkeeping for that many threads can easily swamp the calculation itself.

Comment: Thanks for so many quick responses. The efficiency of the program is unimportant. The purpose of this program is to demonstrate multithreading, and using 10,000 numbers and splitting it like crazy is interesting to say the least, as wasteful as it is, but it demonstrates the capability to do so if needed.

Comment: You can demonstrate multi-threading with 2 threads too. Just keep printing their thread ids in a loop. And speaking of threads, how does one distinguish between threads and processes on linux?